# jquery ajax doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a server-side function using Jquery ajax, it doesn't work, I get no error. what can be the problem ? is there a set of rules to make sure my $ajax will work?

//HTML

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem>aaa</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>bbb</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

//JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DDL").change(function () {                             
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "signToCity.aspx/getStreets",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"              
                });

            });
        });
```

//Serverside

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static void getStreets()
        {                       
         string test="no return:just checking by breakpoint if function is working."

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `data: "{}"` to your ajax call?

Comment: yes - it didn't work, so i try to minimize everything, i want to know what is the core for $ajax to fire

Comment: 1. How are you checking that the call is being made or not? you should use your browser's console (or net tab in the developer tools) to check if the call has been made . 2. Try adding a console.log("test") in your javascript function to see if the function is being called. 3. can you post the HTML?

Comment: I don't see a callback function to handle the return string.

Comment: the string isn't even being returned as far as i can see

Comment: Add next function error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }    in ajax call to get error type

Comment: @valepu  i used google chrome console - got no error, so I used an alert to make sure my dll change works and it did. so I have no Idea what is the problem

Comment: @valepu yes - no return of the string for now, I just want to reach the function on the server side

Comment: @SunnyS.M i tried to add your code - got no error

Comment: have you added Jquery file ?

Comment: @SunnyS.M ofcourse :) Jquery was added

Comment: hahahah sorry bro just confirming.... may I know ajax url and your page on same domain ?

Comment: can you add you complete code in post, so we can go through code to find problem ?

Comment: Have you actually navigated to signToCity.asmx to confirm both your url and to confirm the web method is actually working?

Comment: Can you use the network tab to see if the url is being called? If you click on the XHR button it will filter to show only the ajax calls. If the call appears here then the call is being done, it's just that it has no visible effect server side nor client side

Comment: i think the issue is either that the call is done but you weren't able to see any visible effect or that the .change event is not firing. If checking the "Network" tab will show nothing try to put a console.log before the $.ajax method

Comment: @valepu thank you! it helped me to solve the problem which was on the server side.

Comment: Glad i helped. It would be a good idea to post what you found out as an answer, for future reference

Comment: @valepu I will post a full answer to newers in $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the detail of rules to make a AJAX Call : [See Here in detail](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://api.joind.in/v2.1/talks/10889',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   error: function() {
      $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
   },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
      var $title = $('<h1>').text(data.talks[0].talk_title);
      var $description = $('<p>').text(data.talks[0].talk_description);
      $('#info')
         .append($title)
         .append($description);
   },
   type: 'GET'
});
```

Comment: I added the HTML .. there is nothing more to add...i think.. do i need to add something to web.config maybe ?..

Comment: web config is server configuration file we not need to add anything there

Comment: is your Ajax call URL and page from where ajax request made.. they are on same domain ?

Comment: the function is in signToCity.aspx.cs and the ajax is written in signToCity.aspx.. if that's what you mean

Comment: are you able to access this page through web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your server side code to the following: (change void to string and return value)

**c#**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getStreets()
{
    return "no return:just checking by breakpoint if function is working.";
}
```

**jQuery:** (add handlers for ajax response)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "signToCity.aspx/getStreets",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `clientidmode` to `static` for your web control somewhere?  If not, ASP.NET renders it with an entirely different id

You labeled the follwing as HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem>aaa</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>bbb</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

but it is not HTML, it is your aspx page that will be processed and output html.  Look at the page source and see the actual `HTML` that is rendered.  You will notice your dropdown list is a `select` element with an `id` something like `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Page$#DDL`

Your `jQuery` cant find`$("#DDL")` because it doesnt exist.

#### Option 1:

If your javascript is directly on the `.aspx` page and not external, you can use the following to **print the generated client id to your page**

```
 ...$("#<%=DDL.ClientID%>").change(function () {                             
                $.ajax({...
```

#### Option 2:

Your other option is to **set the ClientIDMode of your `DropDownList` to `static`**, so it doesn't change when the page is rendered

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
                  <asp:ListItem>aaa</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>bbb</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I changes the ClientIDMode to static and nothing is changed

Comment: can you post the actual html in your question?  That will be easier to debug

Answer (score -1):

Could your url be the problem?
`signToCity.aspx/getStreets` doesn't look right. Perhaps it's supposed to be `signToCity/getStreets.aspx`?

Or even just `signToCity/getStreets`?

Comment: according to all the examples online (that I've seen :) ) my url is fine...I tried to change it to your options - no change

Comment: Are you sure? Is signToCity an aspx file on the server? Is getStreets also an aspx file? Are either a directory? A url should follow the pattern `domain/path/resource`, and if signToCity.aspx is a resource, then getStreets after it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yes and i add an example http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx